# How do I access ngRoute's controller from directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I need access to my controller that's provided by ngRoute in directive. Is it possible?

Comment: The answer to this question depends on what you're actually trying to accomplish.  In general you probably don't want to do it the way you're suggesting, so if you shed a little light on the actual goal then we might be able to tell you the Angular Way to do it.

Comment: it would be better if you can tell, the business use case. the way directives are used is, they should be agnostic to the parent, should be independent.  so if a directive needs to know its parent controller, there is something inherently wrong in implementation. Can you please share your business use case.

Comment: You accepted my answer. If this is correct please update your question to refer to ui-router and clarify it's the controller's scope you need access to.

Comment: @HarishR "if a directive needs to know its parent controller, there is something inherently wrong in implementation": not true, this is precisely why the [`require`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-require-) property exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your directive you need to set `scope:true` and then parent scope is available. For example if you have `state` configured as

```
$stateProvider
  .state('main', {
    url: '/main',
    controller: 'MainCtrl',
    templateUrl: 'main.html'
  });
```

Where `MainCtrl` is

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = { data: 'data' };
  $scope.fn = function () {
    alert('MainCtrl function');
  }
});
```

and `main.html` simply

```
<my-directive></my-directive>
```

Where `myDirective` is

```
app.directive('myDirective', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: true,
    template: '<div>MainCtrl data: {{ data | json }}' +
              '<button ng-click="fn()">alert</button></div>' 
  }; 
});
```

And HTML template for all this

```
<body>
  <div>
    <a ui-sref="main">Main state</a><hr>
  </div>
  <div ui-view></div>
</body>
```

Then you'd see something like below, showing `data` set in controller as well as `alert` from controller's function fn.

[image: imgur]

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/iSPDXp

Comment: This is for ui-router, not ngRoute as the question asks

Comment: Also note the question isn't asking for access to the scope, it's asking for access to the controller - IE the thing that `this` binds to when the controller is executed by angular.

Comment: You are right about ui-router but "access to the controller" is as you interpret it. I had doubts but edited answer after it was accepted. Changes are op didn't test before accepting or then question needs editing.

Comment: It's definitely ambiguous. The reason I added a bounty was because I wanted to get the page controller, not the page controller's scope. Clearly that wasn't what the OP wanted

Comment: Maybe question should be edited to match the answer...? Awkward.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** I would not recommend doing this on production code, these methods are more useful for debugging Angular in the console. However, it is a way of accessing a controller from a directive.

There's one way I can think of where you would be able to do this with the use of [angular.element](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element).

```
...
.directive('example', function () {
    return {
        link: function () {
            // Get access to the controller itself.
            var ctrl = angular.element('[ng-view]').controller();

            // Get access to the controller's scope.
            var ctrlScope = angular.element('[ng-view]').scope();
        }
    };
})
...
```

There's probably far better ways of doing whatever it is you want than this. But if you really want to know how to do it, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

in the link function of your directive all you really need is

```
scope.$parent
```

That will get you access to the controllers scope where the directive is used. Although, this is not the best way, it is perhaps the easiest. Its not recommended as $parent could potentially be any controller. Its better to use the

```
transclude: true
```

option on your directive to share the controllers scope.

You can also set individual items on a directives scope from the controller by using the '=' operative like so

```
scope: {
  foo: '=bar'
}
```

Where bar is a var set on the controllers scope. I'm not sure which of these you consider the best.

Answer (score -2):

There is no specific API for this, but if you make your expose your controller on the current scope you can always access the scope data from directive.

Inside controller do

`$scope.controller=this;`

You can now access this controller in your directive directly or passing it through isolated scope.

In fact `controller as` syntax also does something like this.